# Error with Encoding when I create HTML table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My code to create my table head is the following:

```
CreateHeadTable(idDes, idT, ["#", "Empresa", "Dirección", "Consultar"]);

function CreateHeadTable(idDest, idT, arrayHead){
    var mytable = document.createElement("TABLE");
    mytable.setAttribute("id", idT);
    mytable.className = "display";
    mytable.cellPadding = 0;
    mytable.width = "100%";

    var thead = document.createElement("THEAD");
    mytable.appendChild(thead);

    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    thead.appendChild(tr);

    var th, cell;

    for(var row = 0; row < arrayHead.length; row++) {
        th = document.createElement("th");
        cell = document.createTextNode(arrayHead[row].toString());
        th.appendChild(cell);
        tr.appendChild(th);     
    }

    document.getElementById(idDest).appendChild(mytable);
    iniciarTabla(idT);   
}
```

[image]
That word should be: "Dirección" and not "Direcci?n"

I'm using visual studio 2010 and MVC asp.net with razor cshtml
and I put this in my layout main

```
<head> <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> </head>
```

there any way to fix that ??

Comment: Is that a js file? Is that source file encoded as ISO-8859-1?

Comment: No, it's in the razor file__ my js are separate.

Comment: Then you will need to tell ASP to use the ISO-8859-1 to encode the response. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1743961/adding-charset-to-all-asp-net-mvc-http-responses)